# How to show real time HighCharts Line Graph data which is receiving by an API?

Tags: highcharts, angular5, cron-task, real-time-data

I have a Node.js server with Rest Apis. And Client side app on Angula5 based which is consuming those Back-end Apis. Now i want to implement real time high charts on which i want to show real time data effect. Like my api from which i am receiving data

```
/api/gateway/getGraphData
```

How can i show real time data? Data is coming at every second at back-end. So Should i run crone job having my endpoint on Angular app to get data at every crone job call and bind that data to chart?

Comment: Check this [demo](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/live-data)

Comment: in this demo i can't see api call. Did you guide me where is the api call?

Comment: You may not need to call the api just update every second at back-end a CSV file and add this CSV url to the chart

Comment: what if, if i place here my api call url? so will it work?

Comment: I don't think it will, check the [doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.csvURL)

Comment: the demo you mentioned earlier in that demo createChart() function is not calling every second so how chart is updating?

Comment: The chart is updating because of `polling` feature, which `Enables automatic refetching of remote datasets every n seconds`, so you just need to generate the csv file on your server and make it accessible. Here is the documentation: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.enablePolling

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. An AJAX call to fetch data which is loaded when your chart loads. This will continuously fetch data with a certain time interval.

```
function fetchData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://SOME_JSON_URL_HERE.com/',
        success: function(data) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20;
            chart.series[0].addPoint(data.xValue, true, shift);      
            setTimeout(fetchData, 8000);
        },
        cache: false
    });
}


chart = new Highcharts.Chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        events: {
            load: fetchData
        }
    }
});
```